# Blender inset without ngongs

Tags: geometry-nodes

Testing my first geo setup - I just made a very I would say unoptimised way of inset, but now I met an issue where n-gons going to happen, where boolean connected only 2 vertex instead of 4. Is there is any way I can connect all inner square,4 vertex with outter 4 vertex? Similar to what bridge would do I would say.. or similar result what you would get from inset? Basically boolean at the moment is not doing a great job..Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. Question corrected